# number of distinct subsequence

Tags: algorithm, subsequence

### There is a leetcode problem: distinct subsequences.

Given a string S and a string T, count the number of distinct subsequences of T in S.
A subsequence of a string is a new string which is formed from the original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters. (ie, "ACE" is a subsequence of "ABCDE" while "AEC" is not).

Here is an example:
S = "rabbbit", T = "rabbit"
Return 3.

---

### My questions:

Here, I don't understand what is the meaning of ***"count the number of distinct subsequences of T in S"*** 
I think "r", "ra","b" rab", "rabt" etc. are all subsequences of T, and they are also in S. But the return gives answer "3". So, I must have misunderstood the problem, could anyone explain it to me? Just giving me some more typical examples and explanations is OK and don't tell me how to solve it, I hope to do it as an exercise. Thanks in advance

Comment: Interpret the _number of distinct subsequences of T in S_ as: the number of distinct ways to form a subsequence of `S` that is equal to `T`.

Comment: Really thanks for your explanation, I understand this problem now.

Comment: that is the weirdest interpretation of that sentence.  it looks to me like it says: number of distinct subsequences of T in S.  i.e. the number subsequences of T that are distinct and is contained in S.  It looks to me like it should be "number of distinct subsequences of S that are equal to T".  Where a distinct subsequence of S is defined as a tuple S and a list of characters to delete (as defined earlier in the problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can get T="rabbit" from S="rabbbit" by deleting either the first, the second, or the third "b" in S. Hence, the number of possible variants is 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the question. *Count the number of distinct sub-sequences of T in S* means *how many unique appearances of T (rabbit) are there in S (rabbbit).*

The answer is three:

(The **bold** letter being the deleted one)

r a **b** b b i t == rabbit

r a b **b** b i t == rabbit

r a b b **b** i t == rabbit

See? Three *distinct* sub-sequences of the word "rabbit" taken the string "rabbbit". A different character was deleted each time.

Comment: Really thanks for your explanation, I finally understood and solved this problem.